# How to update the value of a public property in all forms? VB.net

Tags: vb.net

This is my code in module1:

```
Module Module1

Private strMessage As String = Form3.TextBox1.Text
Public Property getMessage() As String
    Get
        Return strMessage
    End Get
    Set(ByVal strCustomerFirstName As String)
        strMessage = strCustomerFirstName
    End Set
End Property
```

End Module

I use Form3 to assign the value to strMessage in module1:

```
    Public Class Form3
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        getMessage = TextBox1.Text
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide
    End Sub
End Class
```

But when I update the new value in Form3 the value that is displayed in Form1 didn't update at all. How can I update the value without using the me.close() in form1.

> ```
> Dim numberOfCharactersToDisplay As Integer = 100
> Dim scrollingTextSelector As String
>
> Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>     scrollingTextSelector = getMessage
>
>     Do Until scrollingTextSelector.Length > (getMessage.Length + numberOfCharactersToDisplay)
>         scrollingTextSelector &= " " & getMessage
>     Loop End Sub
> ```

Comment: Try to put breakpoints and use debug to check the  return value of `get Message`

Comment: can you give me a sample code? I'm new to VB. It will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot give you code but you can check it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx). how to use breakpoint

Comment: Why would it?  You have code in the `Load` event handler of `Form1`.  That code only gets executed before the form loads.  If you expect something to happen in the form after it loads then you need code that gets executed after it loads, e.g. the `Click` event handler of a `Button`.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private strMessage As String = Form3.TextBox1.Text

Public Property getMessage() As String
    Get
        Return strMessage
    End Get
    Set(ByVal strCustomerFirstName As String)
        strMessage = strCustomerFirstName
        form3.textbox1.text = strMessage
    End Set
End Property
```